# Serialize a class that extends MovieClip > DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, serialization, arrays

I've been using ByteArray on many of the custom classes I've been needing to store/load, however the ByteArray never seems to serialize a custom class/object that extends MovieClip correctly. There's always missing data or null values upon being read.

I've read here that AMF can't serialize displayObjects and was wondering if there's a good solution that i can use? (Short of shunting the data obj to Json and feeding the string back into my saving.)

Into and Out of ByteArray

```
public static function _SaveTRData(trData:Object):String{
    if(_trackerComp == null){
        return "ERR: -1";
    }
    var resp:String = "";
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    bytes.writeObject(trackerData);
    resp = _trComp.SaveTRData(bytes);//to SQLlite db methods
    if(resp != ""){
        _tr.UpdateStatusMessage(resp);
    }
    return resp;
}

public static function _GetTRData(fileName:String):Object{
    if(_trComp == null){
        return null;
    }
    var resp:ByteArray = _trComp.GetTRData(fileName);//from SQLlite db methods
    resp.position = 0;
    return(resp.readObject());//returned object is passed into graphics pipeline to redraw contained data elements
}
```

Object(s) being stored

```
var trackerData:Object = {arrPolys:new Array(), arrLabels:new Array()};
trackerData.arrPolys = maps.arrPolys();
trackerData.arrLabels = maps.arrLabels();
//Truncated, contains more arrays of objects...

//Each object in arrPolys is a
public class Polygon extends MovieClip{
    //3 private uints
    //3 private bools
    //1 private array
    //3 private custom class Line which extends Shape
}

//Each object in arrLabels is a
public class Label extends MovieClip{
    //Several private strings
    //Several private dynamically generated graphic components
    //Several private label specifications (Strings, Ints, Booleans)
}
```

Comment: Show some code? Are you using registerClassAlias?

Comment: After some testing, ByteArray specifically will not serialize any data from a class that extends MovieClip, (a display object).

I'm looking into IExternalizable with IDataInput and IDataOutput, however keep hitting  signature errors with readExternal() and writeExternal()

Comment: You have a bad design if you need to store MovieClip in ByteArray. You should extract some data model. That data model could be stored as ByteArray. When data is recovered MC should be updated. Take a look at Model-View-Controller or Model-View-Presenter patterns.

Comment: My extension of MovieClip was to leverage several built in features of the MovieClip class without having to rewrite them. 

If i'm understanding you correctly i should rather have generic classes containing just the vars, getters and setters, which is then instantiated into my class that extends MovieClip. (where all the heavy lifting is performed)

Comment: @Reahreic Try to have like "state" class and save it as model. Extract all properties that matter in your context, and serialize them without DisplayObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why they say that display and data should be separate.

Here's the mindset you need to tackle this:

- A polygon is **not** something displayable. It's a list of points
  that are connected. Maybe it has auxiliary information based on those
  points like area of the polygon or if its convex. There could be additional stuff here.
- Then there's a data about how to draw a polygon. It has a line thickness, line color. Maybe a fill. etc.
- Last but not least there's the actual drawing of the polygon. This is your `DisplayObject`.

Depending on what you want to store you save the polygon data and the drawing recipe data which are easily serializable.

On deserialization, you instantiate the appropriate class (`DisplayObject`) and feed the data into it.

**tl, dr**: MVC